# Should a Power BI service Administrator see all workspaces created by other users?

Tags: powerbi

I am an administrator in our PBI tenant. We have another administrator as well. I have created several workspaces (non-private) that the other administrator cannot see. I was thinking that an administrator should be able to see any non-private workspace any one has created without having to be given permission to see the workspace. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tenant admin can't automatically view any workspace but they have the power to add themselves to any workspace via the [Admin Portal Workspaces controls](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/workspaces).

Quoting from [here](https://www.coatesdatastrategies.com/blog/how-much-data-can-a-power-bi-administrator-access):

> All ***metadata*** throughout the tenant is available to the Power BI administrator (ex: if they want to enumerate a list of workspaces, reports, dashboards, etc using the APIs). So, metadata is easily discoverable but -- technically speaking -- a Power BI administrator cannot access ***datasets*** in Power BI unless they have permission to that workspace. However...
>
> A Power BI administrator can grant access to themselves, or a colleague, to any workspace in the Power BI tenant. Which means that ***all data *could* become available to a Power BI administrator if the need arises***. With Power BI administration, there is no separation between control plane and data plane.